# Managing GPU memory in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am wondering if it is possible to create a finalise method for OCaml records? I am creating a GPU database and I am using OCaml for building the DSL to query and manipulate GPU data, and I need a way to free GPU memory when they are eligible for GC (not referenced anymore).

I have creating a binding to my C-based GPU api to allow to malloc, free and manipulate GPU data but I am looking at solutions to free GPU memory when it is not referenced by variables anymore in the toplevel.

```
let bids = (**a 1-dim GPU array*) and asks = (**another 1-dim GPU array*) in
let spread = asks - bids
```

In this example, I would need to free up the GPU memory for the bids and asks vector residing in GPU memory. I guess I need to write my own language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is probably custom blocks, since your data is not pure Caml:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual033.html

> 19.9  Advanced topic: custom blocks
>
> Blocks with tag Custom_tag contain both arbitrary user data and a
>   pointer to a C struct, with type struct custom_operations, that
>   associates user-provided finalization, comparison, hashing,
>   serialization and deserialization functions to this block.

You can attach your C finalization functions to custom blocks. They are called when the block is GCed in OCaml world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Gc.finalise`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Gc.html) to do this. Using GC finalization (American spelling) to control things is quite perilous (or so I've read). For example, finalization functions are not called at program exit. So be careful :-)